# Dropdown menu no JS - Transition-duration doesen't work

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

we have this problem

Here you can see the basic structure of my menu

http://jsfiddle.net/L8FLe/2/

When you follow rapidly the arrow with mouse pointer (go from header to bottom crossing menu) you see immediatly the submenu.

I'm trying to retard this operation (0.7 s) using attribute transition-duration ma don't works. Pratically, i would retard the appearance of submenu, also when mouse pointer go from button gender1 to gender2 so that when you move rapidly the mouse crossing menu you don't see submenu.

Thanks to all, my english is very bad, sorry!

---

My html

```
<p style="margin-left:50px">FOLLOW THE ARROW <BR /><BR /> &darr;</p>

<ul class='dd_menu'>
<li><a href='#nogo'>Gender 1</a>
    <div id="pluto">
    <a href='#nogo1'>Male</a><br />
    <a href='#nogo2'>Female</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href='#nogo'>Gender 2</a>
    <div id="pluto">
    <a href='#nogo1'>Male</a><br />
    <a href='#nogo2'>Female</a>
    </div>
</li>

</ul>
----
```

---

My css

```
.dd_menu { padding:0px; margin:0; list-style-type:none; height:30px; width:500px; margin:55px 0 0 55px; border:#CCC 1px dashed}
.dd_menu li {float:left; height:30px; border-right: solid 1px white; width:95px; }
.dd_menu li a {display:block;  height:28px;  padding:3px 5px 3px 5px;}

.dd_menu li:hover {position:relative; background-color:#DDD;  }

#pluto  {border:#CCC 1px solid; width:100px; display:none;}

.dd_menu li:hover #pluto { display:inline; width:95px; display:block;  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.7s; }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great article about css3 dropdown menus, transition effects, transition timing e.t.c. There is also a section on properly using transition for delay. Check it it will be great:  http://www.identifydesign.net/tutorials/css/pure-css-animated-dropdown-menu/
The info you need is under **Adding Timing** heading.

Also you may check:
W3school article on Transition delays:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-duration.asp

**Edit:**

It may be because of wrong order it should be like:

```
   transition-duration: 0.7s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.7s; /* Firefox 4 */
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transition-duration: 0.7s; /* Opera *
```

Comment: thanks but does not work either. In this example there is no delay in the appearance of the submenu when you pass the mouse over it.

Comment: @Marco Ok Friend I am reviewing it. Just wait a little

Comment: @Marco I have found some stuff on adding delay with transtion. I have edited the answer to add the links. Hope it will solve your problem.